# use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image no funciona Image::make

Tags: laravel, imagen, intervention

Tengo un proyecto en laravel 9, esta funcionando pefectamente localmente con laragon,
al subir en un servidor windows (IIS 10), no esta funcionando la carga de imagenes,

```
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;
```

funciona correctamente el codigo hasta esta linea:

```
 $img = Image::make($imagen->path());
```

alguien aqui que tuvo este mismo problema
desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: leistes los requerimientos de la libreria y que todos esten habilitados?

Comment: Lo mas probable es que te falte permisos de escritura en la carpeta que deseas guardar las imágenes. Recuerda compartir el error que te está dando para poder brindarte una solución más oportuna.